# Assigning a dict to a cell in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I create a dataframe using below

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age'])
```

df looks like below:
[image]

I try to assign a dictionary to a cell and it throws an error:
`df.loc[1,"Name"] = {1:0}`

Error:

```
line_extraction.ipynb Cell 25 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df.loc[1,"Name"] = {1:0}
      2 df

File c:\Dev\.conda\envs\hug_sum\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:716, in _LocationIndexer.__setitem__(self, key, value)
    713 self._has_valid_setitem_indexer(key)
    715 iloc = self if self.name == "iloc" else self.obj.iloc
--> 716 iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value, self.name)

File c:\Dev\.conda\envs\hug_sum\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1691, in _iLocIndexer._setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value, name)
   1688 # align and set the values
   1689 if take_split_path:
   1690     # We have to operate column-wise
-> 1691     self._setitem_with_indexer_split_path(indexer, value, name)
   1692 else:
   1693     self._setitem_single_block(indexer, value, name)

File c:\Dev\.conda\envs\hug_sum\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1712, in _iLocIndexer._setitem_with_indexer_split_path(self, indexer, value, name)
   1709 if (isinstance(value, ABCSeries) and name != "iloc") or isinstance(value, dict):
   1710     from pandas import Series
-> 1712     value = self._align_series(indexer, Series(value))
   1714 # Ensure we have something we can iterate over
   1715 info_axis = indexer[2]

File c:\Dev\.conda\envs\hug_sum\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:2153, in _iLocIndexer._align_series(self, indexer, ser, multiindex_indexer)
   2149         return ser._values.copy()
   2151     return ser.reindex(ax)._values
-> 2153 raise ValueError("Incompatible indexer with Series")

ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `loc indexer` cannot receive dict, tuple, or list as one cell. In this case, use `at`.

```
df.at[1, 'Name'] = {0:1}
```

`df`

```
    Name    Age
0   tom     10
1   {0: 1}  15
2   juli    14
```

Edited answer in response to @Quang Hoang's comment

Comment: @Quang Hoang I take your comments and edit answer

Comment: Thanks. This resolves my issue. Although, do you know why pandas devs chose this weird way to use .at for some stuff and .loc for other?